# cakephp 2.3.0 CakeEmail

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm working with CakePHP 2.3.0 and CakeEmail.

I'm able to send emails without any problems.
in order to remove 
"This email was generated with CakePHP Framework" that is always appended  to sent email 
i was expecting to find and remove

```
<p>This email was sent using the <a href="http://cakephp.org">CakePHP Framework</a></p>
```

but its not part of the default template 
hope this can be done 
Thank you so much!

in cakephp 2.3.2 the content of /app/View/Emails/html/default.ctp looks like this

```
 <?php
    /**
     *
     * PHP 5
     *
     * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
     * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
     *
     * Licensed under The MIT License
     * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
     * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
     *
     * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
     * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
     * @package       app.View.Emails.html
     * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.10.0.1076
     * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
     */
    ?>
    <?php
    $content = explode("\n", $content);

    foreach ($content as $line):
        echo '<p> ' . $line . "</p>\n";
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

And the content of /app/View/Emails/html/default.ctp looks like this

```
    <?php
/**
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.View.Emails.text
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.10.0.1076
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
?>
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

so what will i do to remove this unseen line of code
hope this can be done 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you removed the line from `app\View\Layouts\Emails\html\default.ctp` but there are two formats that can be sent. Html, text or both. Both html and text format have their own layouts. Default format being send is text unless set otherwise with `emailFormat(...)` method so try modifying layout for text format also in `app\View\Layouts\Emails\text\default.ctp` if you havent done so already.

Answer (score 0):

```
please can you comment last php tag from following file
1) app\View\Layouts\Emails\text\default.ctp
2) app\View\Layouts\Emails\html\default.ctp
and then check it works fine
```